# React Router v4 Routing using Browser Route Correctly

Tags: reactjs

I am currently using the React Router v4 and i am trying to render pages stored as different .js files and defining the url to be matched so as to render the proper .js file.But i have tried a few tutorials and i am unable to do so.

Here is the code for the same.

```
//App.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './site_logo.png';

import {logo_styles,search_box_style,submit_button_style,shopping_cart_button_style,background_top_style,Login_button_style} from './style'

class FrontPage extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={search_field:''}
    this.username_input=this.username_input.bind(this)
  }

  username_input(e)
  {
    this.setState({search_field:e.target.value})
  }
  render()
    {
      return(
        <div style={background_top_style}>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.username_input} style={search_box_style}/>
          <button style={submit_button_style}><i class="fa fa-amazon"></i> </button>
          <button style={Login_button_style}>Log In</button>
          <button style={shopping_cart_button_style}><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
          <h1>{this.state.search_field}</h1>
        </div>
      );
    }
}  
export default FrontPage

//Login.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


class Login extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={username:'',password:''}
  }

Login_data_username(e)
{
  this.setState({username:e.target.value})
}

Login_data_password(password)
{
  this.setState({password:password.target.value})
}

render()
{
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
} 
export default Login
 //index.js


`import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import FrontPage from './App';
    import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
    import Login from './Login'
    import {BrowserRouter,Link,Route} from 'react-router-dom'

    class Display extends React.Component
    {
      render()
      {
        return(
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Route path = 'main/' component={FrontPage} />
              <Route path = 'login/' component={Login} />
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<Display/>,document.getElementById('root'))

    registerServiceWorker();`
```

I am unable to figure out what am i doing out.If anybody can help me out i will be grateful.

Comment: When you run this, what do you see on the page?

Comment: I have tried paths like /main and /login and nothing gets rendered.On it's own,both the pages render properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in this part of code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Route path = 'main/' component={FrontPage} />
              <Route path = 'login/' component={Login} />
            </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

The path should be like `'/main'`. Edit your code like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <div>
              <Route path = '/main' component={FrontPage} />
              <Route path = '/login' component={Login} />
            </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Also, don't forget to actually navigate to `'/main'` and `'/login'` using browser URL.

If it still doesn't work, please do mention.

Comment: I tried the same thing yesterday but it didn't work.Thank you for the answer.